# Git clone through https dies of signal 13

Tags: git, https, nixos

The https module for git is dying from a signal 13, and I'm not really sure how to diagnose it. Here is what I am getting:

```
$> git clone https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs

Cloning into 'nixpkgs'...
...
Checking connectivity... done.
error: git-remote-https died of signal 13
```

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. My version is 1.9.4. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems plausible that you have the problem describe [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/error-git-remote-https-died-of-signal-13-td7599771.html)

If that instance the problem was with versions or libcurl older than  7.32.0.  If your curl is older than that version then you need to upgrade.  If it isn't then I would recommend diagnosing per the methods Jeff gives on that link.